# What selections of $g(x)$ give solutions to this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I’m trying to solve $f(x)=f’(x)+g’(x)$ but I don’t know how. $g(x)$ is a known function.

I want to know what selections of $g(x)$ will yield valid solutions, and what those solutions are.

This is a very interesting problem to me because of the simplicity in which it can be written down and because differential equations have many applications in mathematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, for a continuously differentiable $g$,
$$
f'-f=-g'
$$
is a linear ODE with continuous coefficients and right side. By the standard theorems this is unrestrictedly solvable (wherever the coefficients are continuous).

---

More specifically, apply an integrating factor, 
$$
(e^{-x}f(x))'=-e^{-x}g'(x)=-(e^{-x}g(x))'-e^{-x}g(x)
$$
so that after integration
$$
f(x)=Ce^x-g(x)-e^x\int e^{-x}g(x)dx.
$$
So you get solutions for any differentiable $g$, even if in the final formula there are no derivatives of $g$ involved.